# Is there any way to start another app, without full package name?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I want to make a feature, that allows user to write or speak the sentence like "open facebook" and the app launch it. 
Is there any way to open another app using only name of the application? 
i have tried something like this

 `val i = Intent(packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.facebook.katana"))`
`startActivity(i)`
but it requires full package name.

Comment: You can query list of apps in user's device and send intent to matched app with its package name.

Comment: You have to specify the Package name . You can parse all the installed packages(might need some special permission on latest versions) . Then you can just break the query and get the app name and check for the App name in the installed package list and then launch the app .

Comment: Thank you, i did as you both mentioned and it worked